# Stacked Histograms Using R Base Graphics

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Using `ggplot2` it is very easy to create stacked histograms:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) + 
  geom_histogram(colour = 'white')
```

[image]

```
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) + 
  geom_histogram(colour = 'white', position = 'fill')
```

[image]

I would like to know how to create both histograms using only **R base graphics**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate both plots with `barplot()`, based on a frequency table of `Species` and `Sepal.Length`.

```
# Create frequency table
tab <- table(iris$Species, iris$Sepal.Length)

# Stacked barplot
barplot(tab)
```

[image]

```
# Stacked percent barplot
barplot(prop.table(tab, 2)) # Need to convert to marginal table first
```

[image]

Comment: The question was about histograms, not barplots.

Comment: and why exactly are these not histograms?

Comment: The x-axis of a histogram is continuous and values are binned. A barplot plots counts for each category, so if there are distinct values they get their own bar -- they are not binned. In this specific example this only leads to some distortion due to a few values missing (7.3-7.9 only spans 5 bars instead of 7), and you can't do different bin widths or counts. In a setting with more continuous and/or sparse data the difference is much more obvious, one might say catastrophic. Try e.g. `set.seed(1); x <- rnorm(30); barplot(table(x)); hist(x)`