# How to create a stacked histogram using base R?

Tags: r

I have looked into similar questions but had no luck. Here is a sample dataset, but I am only using Sex and Weight variable.

```
structure(list(Name = c("A Lamusi", "Juhamatti Tapio Aaltonen", 
"Andreea Aanei", "Jamale (Djamel-) Aarrass (Ahrass-)", "Nstor Abad Sanjun"
), Sex = c("M", "M", "F", "M", "M"), Age = c(23L, 28L, 22L, 30L, 
23L), Height = c(170L, 184L, 170L, 187L, 167L), Weight = c(60, 
85, 125, 76, 64), Team = c("China", "Finland", "Romania", "France", 
"Spain"), NOC = c("CHN", "FIN", "ROU", "FRA", "ESP"), Games = c("2012 Summer", 
"2014 Winter", "2016 Summer", "2012 Summer", "2016 Summer"), 
    Year = c(2012L, 2014L, 2016L, 2012L, 2016L), Season = c("Summer", 
    "Winter", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer"), City = c("London", 
    "Sochi", "Rio de Janeiro", "London", "Rio de Janeiro"), Sport = c("Judo", 
    "Ice Hockey", "Weightlifting", "Athletics", "Gymnastics"), 
    Event = c("Judo Men's Extra-Lightweight", "Ice Hockey Men's Ice Hockey", 
    "Weightlifting Women's Super-Heavyweight", "Athletics Men's 1,500 metres", 
    "Gymnastics Men's Individual All-Around"), Medal = c(NA, 
    "Bronze", NA, NA, NA), Num_Sports = c("Judo", "Ice Hockey", 
    "Weightlifting", "Athletics", "Gymnastics")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "data.frame")
```

I need to create a barplot which displays the weight count of male and female. I used ggplot for that and created a stacked histogram plot:

[image]

The code for ggplot was easy:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Weight, fill = Sex)) + 
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 10, position="stack")
```

However, I do not know how to create a similar plot using base R. I tried to create a table with weight and sex and then plot the graph, which is a solution from this link: [Stacked Histograms Using R Base Graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365397/stacked-histograms-using-r-base-graphics)

```
tab <- table(data$Sex,data$Weight)
barplot(tab)
```

But it returned a graph with too many bars since Weight is a continuous variable:
[the graph has too many bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4c4JS.jpg)

I also tried `hist(tab)` and `hist(data$Weight)`, which were obviously not correct either.

How can I re-create the graph using base R? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO, see linked post if it helps. Let us know if doesn't, and why.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reminder. I already tried the solution in the post link, however, it is not applicable to my case. I just added a new graph showing the result of the solution as well.

Comment: Please edit your post with example data or use existing example datasets like `mtcars`. Also, add a note that you have looked into other posts with a link, but they didn't work for your case, for x y z reasons.

Comment: Why do you want to switch to base R?

Comment: @sindri_baldur is it an extensive practice from my study which we have to re-do all our analysis with base R. I personally also think it is a bit strange to do so since ggplot is so much easier..

Comment: Try creating your own bins with `cut`, and then using those bins with `table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't enough observations in your example data, so I'll just use `rnorm`:

```r
x <- rnorm(100, 10, 1)
y <- rnorm(100, 12, 1)
```

Use the `plot` to stack your histograms:

```r
h1 <- hist(x, breaks = 10)
h2 <- hist(y, breaks = 10)

par(mar=c(5.1, 4.1, 4.1, 8.1), xpd=TRUE)

plot(h1, col = "Red", xlim = c(6, 16), xlab = "Weight", main = NULL)
plot(h2, col = "Blue", xlim = c(6, 16), add = T)

legend(17, 19,c("f", "m"), fill = c("Red", "Blue"), title = "Sex")
```

[image: stacked histograms]

Comment: Thank you! So interesting to see that everything is literally possible in here :))

Comment: @vvx No problem! I think I was in the middle of an edit when you accepted, so you may not have seen it. I added a legend to better approximate ggplot.

Comment: I think this plot is not actually "stacked". If they are normal distributions, it looks like the blue is simply in front of the red. Our tests also suggest that this solution overlays, rather than stacks the plots.

Comment: For anyone looking for an actual solution for stacked histograms, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43457249/5599595