# Histogram of logistic regression binary classification performance on R

Tags: r

I trained a logistic regression model to predict if a patient was cured (MRD negative)

Thus i would like to produce a histograme such as this one :

[image: Histogram]

But my code does not produce what expected;

Here is my code

```
data <- data.frame(y_true = test$MRD, y_pred = predict( m , newdata = test , type = "response" ))
seuil_classe_0 <- 0.5  
seuil_classe_1 <- 0.5


# Identifier les vrais positifs (VP), les faux positifs (FP) et les autres pour chaque classe
data$VP_0 <- ifelse(data$y_true == 0 & data$y_pred < seuil_classe_0, 1, 0)
data$FP_0 <- ifelse(data$y_true == 1 & data$y_pred < seuil_classe_0, 1, 0)


data$VP_1 <- ifelse(data$y_true == 1 & data$y_pred >= seuil_classe_1, 1, 0)
data$FP_1 <- ifelse(data$y_true == 0 & data$y_pred >= seuil_classe_1, 1, 0)


# Créer un vecteur de couleurs en fonction des classes et des seuils
couleurs <- ifelse(data$VP_0 == 1, "green",
                   ifelse(data$FP_0 == 1, "red",
                          ifelse(data$VP_1 == 1, "blue",
                                 ifelse(data$FP_1 == 1, "orange", "gray"))))

# Définir l'intervalle de l'axe des y (par exemple, de 0 à 50)
intervalles_y <- c(0, 15)

# Créer un histogramme avec des couleurs différentes pour chaque classe
hist(data$y_pred, 
     col = couleurs,
     main = "Histogramme des Probabilités Prédites",
     xlab = "Probabilité Prédite",
     ylab = "Nombre de Patients",
     border = "black",
     ylim = intervalles_y)
```

The colors do not fit well as shown in my picture, anyone has an idea ?

Thank you very much for helping

Comment: We don't have your data, so we can't run your code. We therefore don't know what your plot looks like, what is wrong with it, or what needs to be changed in it. That's why we always ask for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It would be easy to help you if you supplied this; almost impossible without.

Comment: Not sure (refer Allan Cameron's comment) but perhaps you want to plot each of the four groups separately, re https://stackoverflow.com/a/56149834/12957340

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess given that we don't have your data, but with some made up data (see footnote), we can replicate your plot as follows:

```r
library(ggplot2)

data$correct <- as.numeric(data$y_pred > 0.5) == data$y_true
data$group <- paste0(ifelse(data$correct, 'True ', 'False '),
                     ifelse(data$y_pred > 0.5, 'Positive', 'Negative'))

ggplot(data, aes(x = predictions, fill = group)) +
  geom_histogram(breaks = seq(0, 0.9, 0.025),
                 position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(0.37, 0.5, 0.687), linetype = c(2, 1, 2),
             color = c('#c94d58', 'black', '#556b45')) +
  annotate('rect', xmin = c(0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.525, 0.725),
           xmax = c(0.875, 0.425, 0.175, 0.875, 0.875), ymin = c(18, 15, 9, 15, 9), 
           ymax = c(20, 17.5, 12.5, 17.5, 12.5), fill = 'white', color = 'black') +
  annotate('text', label = c('Standard confidence', 
                              'Predicted persistent\nMRD (<0.5)',
                              'High\nconfidence\n(<0.370)',
                              'Predicted persistent\nMRD (>0.5)',
                              'High\nconfidence\n(>0.687)'),
           x = c(0.475, 0.225, 0.1, 0.69, 0.8), 
           y = c(19, 16.25, 11, 16.25, 11)) +
  annotate('segment', x = c(0.37, 0.687), xend = c(0.025, 0.9),
           y = c(14, 14), yend = c(14, 14), 
           arrow = arrow(type = 'closed', length = unit(3, 'mm'))) +
  scale_fill_manual(NULL,
                    values = c('#f4b2ba', '#c94d58', '#cae2a6', '#556b45'),
                    breaks = c('True Negative', 'False Negative', 
                               'True Positive', 'False Positive')) +
  scale_y_continuous('Number of patients', limits = c(0, 20)) +
  labs(x = 'Probability of prediction') +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA),
        legend.background = element_rect())
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

```r
set.seed(1)

predictions <- rbeta(200, 3, 3)

data <- data.frame(y_true = rbinom(200, 1, predictions), y_pred = predictions)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it does work perfectly !