# R - Empiled histogram for two continuous variables

Tags: r, histogram

I want to make a cumulative histogram like the first one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365397/stacked-histograms-using-r-base-graphics)

I have two continuous variables of income (one is the total income of  households and the other is the income of one individual in the household).

However, and even though there are already many questions in Stackoverflow, I can't manage to make this histogram.

My dataset is called df and the variable for the household is df$household and the other one df$individual.

I tried doing this

```
ggplot(df, aes(group = individual, x = household, fill= individual), colour = c("red", "blue")) + geom_histogram() + xlim(0, 350000)
```

I think I am completely wrong with the fill thing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are more likely to get a good answer if you include some sample data. In this case, it's not too difficult to create some sample data that will roughly match the shape of your data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(69)

individual <- round(rgamma(1000, 2.5, 1/11000))
household  <- round(individual + runif(1000, 0, 30000))

df <- data.frame(household, individual)
```

This should give us some sensible numbers:

```
head(df)
#>   household individual
#> 1     44277      23217
#> 2     55581      28208
#> 3     36186      17100
#> 4     39693      36174
#> 5     27371      16424
#> 6     16406       9615
```

And we can check that their distributions are also sensible:

```r
hist(df$household)
```

[image]

```r
hist(df$individual)
```

[image]

Now we can move onto the answer proper!

One of the reasons why you're not getting the plot you want is that your data is not in the same format as the `iris` data. The two stacked histograms in the linked question are not histograms of two continuous variables in different columns, but subsets of the *same column*, coloured according to species, which is in another column.

It is certainly possible to draw histograms for both your variables on a single plot:

```r
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x = household), fill = "gold") + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x = individual), fill = "tomato", alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

...but of course, these are not stacked. The reason for this is that you have two separate variables, and need to independently create two histograms from them. These "don't know" anything about each other, so they can't stack.

So what's the solution? As in many plotting problems, the solution involves preparing your data so that it is in the format *that you wish to present*. You wish to present all the incomes as a single big histogram, but with parts of the bars coloured in according to whether they are individual incomes or household incomes. In other words, you need to get all your incomes into a single column, and have "household" and "individual" as labels in a grouping column. This is known as *long format* data, and it usually makes plotting easier if you can get your data into this format.

In your case, this is quite straightforward using `pivot_longer` from the `tidyr` package:

```r
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = c("household", "individual"))
#> # A tibble: 2,000 x 2
#>    name       value
#>    <chr>      <dbl>
#>  1 household  44277
#>  2 individual 23217
#>  3 household  55581
#>  4 individual 28208
#>  5 household  36186
#>  6 individual 17100
#>  7 household  39693
#>  8 individual 36174
#>  9 household  27371
#> 10 individual 16424
#> # ... with 1,990 more rows
```

Doing that makes the plot really easy (I've added a couple of scales and theme elements just to make it more visually appealing):

```r
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c("household", "individual")) %>%
  ggplot() + 
    geom_histogram(aes(x = value, fill = name), colour = "black") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("gold", "dodgerblue")) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:12 * 10000) + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
    labs(x = "Income ($)", y = "Number", title = "Income distribution")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>